# Set indexed over another set in Julia

Tags: julia-jump

If I have sets:

**set F := G1 G2;**
and
**set PR[G1] := p1 p2;
set PR[G2] := p3 p4;**

how to make the set PR in Julia. For each element of F a specific set of elements belong to PR.
Thank you!
Nikola

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use something like

```
F = [:G1, :G1]
PR = Dict(:G1 => [:p1, :p2], :G2 => [:p3, :p4])
```

To help more, you will need to provide more information.